# how to block an image from loading into my html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using object to load another website into my html page but i want to block some specific images which are showing from that site. I know the link of the images but don't know how to block these

Comment: Could you be more specific how you're loading the images using "object"? Are you parsing a JSON response containing links to the images?

Comment: I'm loading a specific site by using object but want to block some images from that url.                                                                                        <object type="text/html" data="url" width="400" height="500" ></object>

Comment: Can you add the code that you're using to load the site?